# Why can't the variable be passed?

Tags: powershell

I have the following problem. I get no output with the following command and no error message either. However, if I take the line by itself and replace $n with the username or just part of it, it works.

```
$n = Read-Host -Prompt "Benutzer eingeben"
    
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and Name -like "*$n*"} -Properties Name, DisplayName, msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | Select-Object -Property Name, Displayname,@{Name="Expiration Date";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```

I would be grateful for a tip

Answer (score 4):

If curly braces are used to enclose the *filter*, the variable(in this case it's `$n`) should not be quoted.

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and Name -like $n} -Properties Name, DisplayName, msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed | Select-Object -Property Name, Displayname,@{Name="Expiration Date";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```

Here is the relevant part from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps).

> if the `filter` expression is double-quoted, the variable should be
> enclosed using single quotation marks: `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$UserName'"`. On the contrary, if curly braces are used to enclose the
> filter, the variable should not be quoted at all: `Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $UserName}`.